# why am i getting 'IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 20' when the range of the index is [X, Y]?

Tags: python

EDIT: Im now getting a different error message having fixed the initial probelem by replacing line 9 with : for index, y in enumerate(original_cocrystal_labels[x]):

however now im getting another error saying " index 34 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 34"

I am currently developing a machine learning algorithm to help predict the formation of cocrystals that would be of use to the pharmaceutical industry. My knowledge of code is limited because I am a chemist at heart and use code to enhance my studies. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I am using spyder for this, but i got the error listed above and im not sure why its giving me a range of values when the only range defined in the script was [x, y]. I understand that if the range is 1-5, it is represented as [0, 1, 2 , 3, 4] on python so im not sure where to go from here. the code is below. The full error message is as follows:

"**File "C:\Users\cianm.spyder-py3\THIS IS THE ONE YOU WANT.py", line 278, in Run_SVM_on_external_test
train_descrs.append(cocrystal_descrs[x, y])
IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 20"**

```
      '''def Run_SVM_on_external_test(cocrystal_descrs, test_descrs, original_cocrystal_labels):  
         number_of_columns = len(original_cocrystal_labels)
         column_indices = np.arange(number_of_columns)
               train_descrs = []
               train_labels = []

        #For each column of APIs, add the descriptors to the training set of descriptors if the 
         outcome of the experiment is known (not 2)
              for x in column_indices:
                 for y in range(len(original_cocrystal_labels[x])):
                 if original_cocrystal_labels[x, y] != 2:
                   train_descrs.append(cocrystal_descrs[x, y])
                   train_labels.append(original_cocrystal_labels[x, y])
```

-descriptors are the interactions of molecules, defined in rdkit (cheminformatics tool)
-API = Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient

Thank you in advance, would be happy to provide more info.

Comment: doesn't this >>> `range(len(original_cocrystal_labels[x]))` <<< give you the size of the collection, not the index of the last item in the collection? i thot you would need to subtract `1` from that to get the proper range - `0..19` instead of `0..20`.

Comment: I know what you are implying but im not sure that is the solution, as i have tried this in different ways and it has not worked. Still cannot figure this out

Comment: i am barely familiar with python, but it looks like that index is off-by-one ... and that would give you an index that is out of range by one.

Comment: That was the initial problem but now the index is out by 34...

Comment: arg! i am lost ... hopefully some kind guru will drop in with a better understanding of your problem. i will return to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]